# Debug infinite loops in C++ using gdb and codelite

Tags: c++, gdb, codelite

I have a really large code and when I try to run it in codelite, the codelite interface becomes non-responsive and I have to kill it. This usually happens in case of infinite loops.

I tried to put breakpoints in multiple places of the code to find the problem, but no luck so far. The execution halts after a while from the time that I start running the program. What is the best way of detecting such infinite loops? Codelite doesn't have a "stop" button AFAIK.

**EDIT:**
I ended up adding a lot of cout statements and ran the executable in a terminal rather than gdb. This helped finding what the program is doing after a really long time.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to run the code for a while and then use the debugger to suspend execution without using breakpoints. If you are lucky, the call stack should indicate the bit of code that you are getting stuck in.

Failing that you will need to pepper your code with logging statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "suspend execution without using breakpoints" ?

Comment: On gdb you can press Ctrl C to suspend or halt execution. IDE normally have a stop button.

Comment: Thanks. At least for me, Codelite IDE is completely non-responsive, and no menu or button is enabled.

Comment: +1 for 'pepper your code with logging statements' :) that's what I'll be forced to do for the next N hours.

Comment: 'pepper your code with logging statements' is what I do all the time: works equally well in C++, Perl, Tcl... Just make sure you can turn easily turn them on/off. :)